# Mypy strict optional checking fails with call to another class method to set optionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I create a class and setup the `writer` and `reader` as optionals set to `None` in `__init__`. Correct usage would require calling `open` before anything else, to ensure the `writer` and `reader` are correctly initialized.

In the `read_write` method I check for `None` and if needed initializing is automatically done. However Mypy still treats this as an Strict Optional Checking Error.

```
import asyncio
from typing import Optional


class AsyncTest:
    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int = 502) -> None:
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.writer: Optional[asyncio.StreamWriter] = None
        self.reader: Optional[asyncio.StreamReader] = None

    async def open(self) -> None:
        self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.host, self.port)

    async def read_write(self) -> None:
        if self.writer is None or self.reader is None:
            await self.open()

        self.writer.write(b'')
        await self.writer.drain()
        resp = await self.reader.readexactly(100)

    async def close(self) -> None:
        if self.writer:
            self.writer.close()
            await self.writer.wait_closed()
```

Gives:

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py:19: error: Item "None" of "Optional[StreamWriter]" has no attribute "write"
test.py:20: error: Item "None" of "Optional[StreamWriter]" has no attribute "drain"
test.py:21: error: Item "None" of "Optional[StreamReader]" has no attribute "readexactly"
```

Now if I change the `read_write` method by replacing the call to `self.open()` with the call to `open_connection` Mypy no longer complains.

```
async def read_write(self) -> None:
    if self.writer is None or self.reader is None:
        self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.host, self.port)

    self.writer.write(b'')
    await self.writer.drain()
    resp = await self.reader.readexactly(100)
```

I can obviously disable strict optional checking for that file in Mypy as a temporary solution, but is there a way to get this to work? This would require Mypy to follow the method call to `open` and check whether it sets the `self.writer` and `self.reader` attributes.

In this specific small example the `open_connection` could be put directly inside the `read_write` and completely remove the `open` method, but that hardly seems optimal if the `open` method grows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyPy is only aware of signatures, not side-effects. The signature of `open` cannot express that `writer` and `reader` are defined after calling it.

Instead of externally checking if the object has been "opened" and calling `open` otherwise, move the checking and opening into a method. This method can statically guarantee providing reader/writer, and dynamically memoize them.

```
class AsyncTest:
    ...

    # method always provides valid reader/writer
    async def _connection(self) -> Tuple[asyncio.StreamReader, asyncio.StreamWriter]:
        # internally check if already opened
        if self.reader is None or self.writer is None:
            self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.host, self.port)
        return self.reader, self.writer

    async def read_write(self) -> None:
        # other methods call connection method unconditionally
        reader, writer = self._connection()
        writer.write(b'')
        await writer.drain()
        resp = await reader.readexactly(100)
```